# C# Preventing insert to database when user clicks back in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

So I have a page that loads a form with GET, and when the form is submitted via POST, I have the following redirect:

```
string message = Constants.Home.ThankYou.HaveAdditionalQuestions2;
string title = "Thank you";
return RedirectToAction("ThankYou", "Home", new { message, title });
```

It is redirecting to an actionresult (ThankYou) within a controller (Home), and passes in a specific message and title as this is a thank you page that gets reused. The user also gets logged out.

On submission of the form, a row is added into a table in the database. If the user clicks 'back' on their browser from the thank you page, it loads up the form again and they can still see their previous responses and resubmit, adding a new row into the table. On submit, they aren't redirected to the thank you but rather the login page (since they were logged out) - the issue is that it still adds another row into the table.

Is there any way to prevent the row being inserted into the table the second time around? The way it redirects to the login page is fine, I just want to prevent that second row insert.

I am using C#, ASP.NET

Edited to add some code based on someone's question: this is what the GET looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult InformedConsent(int enrollmentId)
{
   SelfServeInformedConsentModel consentModel = new 
          SelfServeInformedConsentModel(enrollmentId);
   return View("SelfServeInformedConsent", consentModel);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say with the information that you provided.  There are multiple ways to achieve what  you are asking, but it mostly depends on your implementation.  For one, what does the controller look like that is loading the initial form?  Additionally, with the redirect to login page, is the user being logged out after submitting the form?

Comment: @WiseGuy added in the code that loads the initial form. It returns the view which has all the inputs, then the form itself has  `@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveInformedConsent", "Home", FormMethod.Post))`  And yes, the user gets logged out after submitting the form

Comment: Ok, so if the user navigates back to this InformedConsent controller, query the enrollmentId in your database and see if a record has already been created.  If it has then Redirect the user to whichever page you expect them to be on.  

Wrap an if else
if(enrollmentidalreadyupdated(){

 RedirectUser()
}
else{

updateDatabaseBusinessAsUsual()
}

It sounds like you are already using the Post /Redirect/Get pattern, so this should work fine.

Comment: @WiseGuy the thing is, they are technically allowed to have multiple rows per enrollmentid in this table (the idea is they can come back to this page at a later date and change their answer. The history is their answers is saved in this table). So that won't work if they are coming back a second time (using intended flow)

Comment: Maybe you could use a separate controller action for subsequent entries?